# Using Spring Cloud Data Flow with Azure Service Bus

Tags: spring, azureservicebus, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to find some examples of Spring Cloud Data Flow and Azure Service Bus setup. .

I have found https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/tree/master/spring-cloud-azure-stream-binder/spring-cloud-azure-servicebus-topic-stream-binder but it is still in RC and I do not see any examples (which cover Spring Cloud Data Flow) there.

Could you please help me to understand if I can use Spring Cloud Data Flow and Azure Service Bus together?

I was able to run examples with Kafka and RabbitMQ, but I cannot find anything about Azure Service Bus that can be used as the integration solution for Spring Cloud Data Flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Data Flow doesn't necessarily need to know what messaging layer you choose to run your applications on. Hence, your question is more likely related to how one can run the application with Azure Service Bus using `Spring Cloud Stream`.

This is one such a sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub?view=azure-java-stable

Once the application is built using Spring Cloud Stream (using the Azure event hub binder), you can then manage these applications using Spring Cloud Data Flow as Streaming applications.